# Tabstrip hide other controls, how to figure out?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I created a user form within a spreadsheet 2013 and put some controls such as button, textbox, label on the form, then I put a tabstrip control on the form and I want to put these controls which are created before tabstrip to the tabstrip control, but after I drag these controls to it, they become invisible, I don't know how to show them on the tabstrip, do you guys have a way to do so?

see below screenshot, the Cancel button will be hide by this tabstrip.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not drag the control on the tabstrip. Create a new control or cut and past the controls on the tabstrip. Be carefull with cutting and pasting as sometimes events aren't connected anymore (at least that is what happend to me in VB6).

Answer (score 0):

Select all the controls you need to move to the tab. Use the Ctrl+X keyboard shortcut to cut the controls. Then select the tab where you need to paste them and press the Ctrl+V keyborad shortcut.